# How do I add postcss autoprefixer to my ESBuild CSS compiling section of config.js?

Tags: postcss, autoprefixer, esbuild

I am using ESBuild with this very simple config.js file. I would love to utilise the **postcss autoprefixer** plugin however am having difficulty knowing how to add it to my CSS compiling section. Would anybody be able to help me solve this ?

```
//  Tools
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from 'path';
import esbuild from "esbuild";
import postcss from "postcss";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

// CSS files
const cssFiles = [ "assets/pre-bundle-css/style.css" ]

// Compiles nested CSS files to CSS
const cssContext = await esbuild.context({
  entryPoints: cssFiles,
  outdir: "assets/css",
  minify: false,
  bundle: true,
  sourcemap: true
})

await cssContext.watch();
```